# Does Cloud Endpoint and API Gateway (GCP) support Websocket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi, api-gateway, google-cloud-api-gateway

I would like to ask everyone about the limitation of these services
Cloud Endpoint and API Gateway (Beta) on the Google Cloud Platform.
These services are support WebSocket protocol?

Because I can't find the docs official reference about it.

As I know the ESP is already suport WebSocket
https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/blob/master/start_esp/start_esp.py#L535

But I still confused. It's possible to write the rule/config on OpenAPI docs (swagger 2) ?
I try to find the apporach to do it. many people suggest to use another tools for make it such as asyncapi.

So the Cloud Endpoints and API Gateway (Beta) are support websocket protocol?

Comment: AFAIK, it's streaming channel aren't supported by API Gateway (I was in the Alpha and I saw a topic like this when I was in my previous company. But I haven't access to my email and so, I can't be 100% sure about this; and it could be evolved in the meantime!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, Google Cloud Endpoints and API Gateway, both do not support Websockets.

The flag --enable_websocket seems to be deprecated and doesn't have any effect over Cloud Endpoints.

I have created a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/176472002) in Google Public Issue Tracker for the support of Websockets in API Gateway. Please track the feature request for all the future updates regarding the support of Websockets.

Comment: The docs say that while the `--enable_websocket` flag is deprecated, websockets should be enabled by default: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/migrate-to-esp-v2#deprecated-flags. However it seems that ESPv2 has an issue with closing the WS connection after 15s: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2/issues/704

Comment: Sadly, the Feature Request referenced above has been closed as "Won't Fix" Google recommends using the more expensive Apigee product.